# Generate JSON with property names that include dot using SELECT FOR JSON

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, json, sql-server-2019

I need to generate the folowing JSON payload (shortened) from a table in SQL Server. Please note the dot in the property name. This is a special syntax called OData.

```
{
  "Id" : "A1",
  "value": {
    "createdonbehalfby@odata.bind": "systemusers(key='AAAA12334')"
  }
}
```

Imagine the table is like the following:

| Id | CreatedBy |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | AAAA12334 |

I have tried the following T-SQL command:

```
SELECT [Id], [CreatedBy] AS [value.createdonbehalfby@odata.bind]
FROM [Account]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Which obviously results to:

```
{
  "Id" : "A1",
  "value": {
    "createdonbehalfby@odata": {
      "bind": "systemusers(key='AAAA12334')"
    }
  }
}
```

I have already read the full documentation around JSON functionality in SQL Server thoroughly and no where in the documentation escaping dot in property names has been described.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this one out.  However, meanwhile you might find these helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 .  FOR JSON PATH splits and FOR JSON AUTO leaves it more "lumped".  What you want is a hybrid.  I'm also having difficulties wrapping this as a common table expression in a larger query, as I get e.g. `No column name was specified for column 1 of 'cte'`

Comment: I have read them all. Thanks for your comment. The hybrid approach was indeed the approach I took finally to make it work without making it overly complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FOR JSON AUTO` which ignores `.` characters in keys.

In this case, you need to place it in a subquery, otherwise you cannot get the `value` key

````sql
SELECT
  [Id],
  JSON_QUERY((
    SELECT
      [CreatedBy] AS [createdonbehalfby@odata.bind]
    FROM (VALUES(1)) v(dummy)   -- because AUTO needs at least one table
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  )) AS value
FROM [Account]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER```
````

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a9621600c1c61769bd49907e3fbe8c7)

| Result |
| --- |
| {"Id":"A1","value":{"createdonbehalfby@odata.bind":"AAAA12334"}} |

Answer (score 1):

One solution (in addition to my other answer) is to be a bit more explicit in the JSON structure you wish to generate.  Basically, here you are providing FOR JSON with some already properly-parsed JSON code.

```
SELECT
    [Id], 
    JSON_QUERY('{"createdonbehalfby@odata.bind":"'+CreatedBy+'"}') as value
FROM (SELECT 'A1'  as ID, 'AAAA12334' as CreatedBy) AS account
FOR JSON PATH , without_array_wrapper
```

This solution retains the column name generated by FOR JSON.[image: MS SSMS screenshot]

Comment: The real statements that I'm working on are actually a lot bigger that the portion I posted above, but to be honest I ended up using a different approach that is not far from your idea. The main blocking is the fact that there's no way to escape dot in FOR JSON PATH.

Comment: So at the end my workaround is to use nested `SELECT` statements. This kind of statement can easily accommodate several more columns and still remain readable/ maintainable. 
    SELECT [Id], JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT [CreatedBy] FROM [Account] AS [Value]
      WHERE [Value].[Id] = [Payload].[Id]
      FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS [Value]
    FROM [Account] AS [Payload]
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create your own escape sequence, and then use procedural T-SQL with @variables, rather than pure relational query language.

Given the inability to directly escape characters in strings for the FOR JSON parser(*), here we create our own escape sequence which we later have to replace manually.

```
DECLARE @str as nvarchar(MAX) = (
    SELECT
        [Id], 
        [CreatedBy] AS [value.createdonbehalfby@odata%2Ebind]
    FROM (SELECT 'A1'  as ID, 'AAAA12334' as CreatedBy) AS account -- your dummy data
    FOR JSON PATH , without_array_wrapper)
set @str=REPLACE(@str,'%2E','.')
select @str as formatted_json
```

where `%2E` was used because it is the escape sequence for a `.` character in URIs

Obviously if `%2E` could conceivably be part of the value portion of the innermost key, you might have to devise a different substitution or use a more robust parser to only target the particular key that you wanted.

(*)I tried at first to see if FOR JSON would use `\` , `%20` and `&nbsp;` to escape a space character within a string, but none of those worked.

Note that an attempt to try to use the self-escaped string in a subquery or cte -- rather than using a procedural variable as an intermediary -- failed. The column name generated by FOR JSON is a "random" GUID value (note: see screenshot provided for other answer) that I couldn't figure out how to extract.  T-SQL has no way of selecting the column by position, so doing something like `SELECT  COLUMN(1) FROM (...)` does not work. You can't even reference the column by embedding it in a subquery and wrapping with a `SELECT * FROM (...) AS sq`, as that produces the error: `No column name was specified for column 1 of 'sq'`.

Similarly `UNION`s where you bind the "subquery" result to a dummy table with a defined column name didn't seem to be a fruitful path either, as JSON parsing appears to operate after the union operation is complete. Parentheses didn't appear to correct this in my limited testing.

Comment: I have been down this route as well. It's like a dead-end :)